# Side by Side iframes.....FROM embed codes in WordPress

Tags: iframe

I have a couple of giphy GIFs that I'd like side by side not vertical, all that I am using are the embed codes.

```
<iframe src="//giphy.com/embed/5wWf7GX8ia4T1wiMPEA" width="120" height="90" frameBorder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

is there something i can do to add to these codes to enable side by side ...ness, to happen? or do i have to actually figure out how to script something ?  cuz it would be great if i can just change or add some words.

thank you for reading this

here is the entire code for the post

```
<iframe id="visor53e023f8f288a1e6698b4568" width="480" height="360" src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><script src="//studio.themadvideo.com/player/js/MadVideo.js.php?id=53e023f8f288a1e6698b4568"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it's hard to answer with so little info, but try adding a display: inline-block; to the iframes style.

```
     <iframe class="side-by-side-iframe" />
     .side-by-side {
          display: inline-block;
          width: 50%; //or just leave it blank if they are small enough
     }
```

This should solve it, and they will display in the same line, unless they are too big for the line.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, here's the link http://contextualadvertisingin2015.com/ghp-nirvana-rockin-robin/ i added your code before the two iframes, and one disappeared, i'm going to post the code for this post

Comment: Then my solution works, just make sure you delete the br between the two iframes, you can also always add inline style: `<iframe style="display:inline-block;" />`

Comment: is there a br ? sorry, i didn't see it, i'll check again

Comment: there's no br anywhere unless when you type br you don't mean the letters 'b' 'r' sorry super bad at this stuff

Comment: http://imgur.com/f2Ey0H4 then what's this? :) took it from your site, and br I mean <br /> tag which is a line breaker.

Comment: thank you for the quick response, where i put your code just makes the gif it appears before disappear

Comment: Just removing the <br> tag worked for me: http://imgur.com/EwK8l1d didn't even need the display: inline-block; style. try it, let me know if it works.

Comment: no i believe you, i'm just using wordpress, let's see if i can figure this out, thanks a tonne for doing this though, i hope i can get my site to look as well as you've made my site look :)

Comment: Np, unfortunately I have 0 experience with wordpress so you are on your own there, good luck :)

Comment: yeah, i have no idea how you did that, how do i get to the html of just a single post? in wordpress, not sure if you know that, guess i'll look for a plugin, or view source copy paste edit then paste back in wordpress, this is interesting,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, it's waaaay easier than even I could expect, simply go into the visual tab, drag it so the GIFs appear horizontal.....that's it, no coding, nothing.  If it's the wrong size, just move one out of the line then ... back into the line.  Or in the Text post tab, just place all the iframes like so

```
<iframe src="//giphy.com/embed/5wWf7GZTUCuUTm5u8TK" width="120" height="90" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe><iframe src="//giphy.com/embed/ToMjGpvMXxv6uUaCL9C" width="120" height="90" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe><iframe src="//giphy.com/embed/HishDXMdGANR6" width="120" height="90" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

basically just place everything (the embeds you want horizontally next to each other, literally either textually or drag and drop so it's all side by side and it'll probably appear side by side, i'm tired and my mind is blown i added the random victory GIF so i'd remember this moment, thanks Pinhas for figuring it out in your way as well.